# how to limit query in OrientDB by two input params

Tags: orientdb, traversal, orientdb2.2

I've got the following structure in DB:

```
class(V): @city (Name, X, Y)
class(V): @route(Name)
class(V): @Alternative_Route(Name) extends from @route

class(E): @has_route_to 
class(E): @has_subroute
```

The Edges are connected to the Vertices like this:

```
city -> has_route_to -> route -> has_route_to -> city
route -> has_subroute -> city
```

As input I've got two points: City1 and City2.
 
For intance I need to see what subroutes we have between City1 and City2. 
I'm writing the following query:

```
traverse outE('has_route_to'), has_route_to.in 
from 
(select * from City where Name = 'City1')
```

But if I execute it *I'll see all routes from City1, not only from City1 to City2.* 
**It is possible to say to OrientDB: show me all points between City1 and City2 only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select from route where (Name in (select both('has_route_to').Name from City where Name = "City1")) and (Name in (select both('has_route_to').Name from City where Name = "City2"))
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks Michela, that helps